# VB.NET. How to convert a textbox input or a string into an arithmetic formula?

Tags: vb.net, string, math, formula

I am trying to create a grading system where you can choose your own subject and components(recitation, quiz etc) and as well as customize the formula... I will be using ddl language to create the fields and tables in the database so all's well with that, however, I have a big problem with the formula... I do not know how I can convert the string formula (from the textbox or the database) containing "variable names" into a workable formula that the system will recognize.

short example.

I declare three integers a, b & c with corresponding values (a =1, b=2, c=3). then let the user input a formula in a textbox.

example: textbox1: a+c

then equate the results using b...

this is where the problem lies, the program reads it as plain string and does not recognize the variable DX

How will I do this?

Comment: You'll need to use a mathematical-expression parser (use a library or write your own). They'll allow you to extract symbols (variables) and let you provide concrete values before the expressions are evaluated.

Comment: If you don't want to use 3rd party libraries this task is a great way to learn about reflection and runtime-compilation. Check the `VBCodeProvider` class. You basically create sourcecode for a function containing the user input as a formula, then use the .NET compiler to compile it at runtime and then you access the newly created assembly from your program. You may need to replace some variable names with parameter indizes but it is easier than it sounds. It is a very powerful tool to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Some libraries which can evaluate simple math expression strings in .NET are:

- [Simple math explorer](http://simplemathparser.codeplex.com/)
- [Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator](http://flee.codeplex.com/)
- [ILCalc](http://ilcalc.codeplex.com/)
- MathExpressions library used in [Calculator.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2007/05/05/calculator-net-calculator-that-evaluates-math-expressions.aspx)
- [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)
- [This post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18481/Dynamic-formula-calculator-evaluator-in-VB-NET) describes the implementation of a dynamic formula calculator/evaluator in VB.NET. In case you want to implement something out of the ordinary, you could alter the provided code.

Hope I helped!